# ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing - Do not display the content of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is how I have come in trouble with the indication my url to be user friendly all the way.

I've tried to do like this:

```
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Nyheder",
     "nyheder/{id}/{url}", "~/nyheder.aspx");

routeCollection.MapPageRoute("nyheder", "nyheder/{id}/{url}", "~/nyheder.aspx");
```

**I have done this in Global.asax**

Trouble is that it will not be some content that is on nyhedes ago. I've done like this on the front page where news is displayed

```
/Nyheder/<%# Eval("id") %>/<%# Eval("url") %>
```

- Yes, I have it here into a Repeater to print content.

Was it all is that it in no way want to download ID as I have set it to do, but if I put it to do like this it works just fine.

```
/Nyheder.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>&?url=<%# Eval("url") %>
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you please make it more clear what your problem is? Perhaps run it by a friend who speaks better English?

Comment: @mason Yes sorry my bad english.

I try to make it more clear. My problem is such that I want to for a neat URL of the site that you see at the top of the question, I like to be nice example right /nyheder/11/hello-world

Comment: That's not a problem. That's a goal. What is the problem that is preventing you from accomplishing your goal?

Comment: @mason My problem is that it will not retrieve id so it can find content when you enter the page